# Question about NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

If I have a NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *principalTable;
```

and I have a other NSMutableArray:

```
NSMutableArray *secondTable;
```

and I do this:

```
[secondTable addObject:@"string"];

[principalTable addObject: secondTable];

[secondTable removeAllObjects];
```

The principalTable has 1 object, but this object has nothing inside. So my question is:

- When I add a object in a array, the array point on the object, or copy the object in the array?
- And is it the same thing when I add in a nsmutabledictionnary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[secondTable addObject:@"string"];

[principalTable addObject: secondTable];

[secondTable removeAllObjects];
```

When you do the above, `principalTable` will contain a reference to the `secondTable` NSMutableArray instance and will *not* directly contain the string.   Thus, when you `removeAllObjects`, you are emptying `secondTable` and `principalTable` will continue to hold a reference to that now-empty mutable array.

None of your code copies anything.

`NSMutableDictionary` copies keys.  Not values.

Comment: So if I'm in a loop I must create a new table each time and add it to principalTable?

Comment: Depends on your needs; if you want an array of arrays then you would need a new array each pass.  If you want an array of strings, you don't need the second array at all.

Answer (score 0):

The array contains a reference (i.e. a pointer) to the object that you added. Thus when you removed all objects from secondTable, you removed the from the same array that is an element of principle table.